# Use interfaces to implement pre-coded abilities

Tags: java

I'm making a game with different types of mobs in it. There is also a list of interfaces, each representing an ability that a mob can have. Let's say I have 100 objects extending the mob class, each one containing a different list of mob-applicable abilities (swing, explode, jump, etc.). All implementing these interfaces would do is to add blank methods to the class. If the usage of the ability is constant between all mobs, how would I make it so the ability is 
pre-written so that I wouldn't need to write it again for every mob that implements it?

I do know of default methods, but they are static and don't have access to any of the mob's variables unless I pass "this" as a parameter which is something I don't want to do.

I am also aware that were there to be a solution to the problem using interfaces, those interfaces could only ever be implemented by a mob.

Thanks.

Comment: Use inheritance and create getters and setters for your base mob class that can access your private properties. Then override or add the methods that enable specific mob functionality on to the overriding class. I think you may also be confused about static versus inherited methods I think.

Comment: That's what I was originally going to do, but then I realized how much of a pain that would be. If I had 100 different abilities, and since any mob could implement any number of abilities, I would have to create an insane amount of subclasses, and whenever I added a new mob, I would have to completely change the inheritance tree to optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, a possible solution is to compose abilities instead of inheriting them.

```
interface Ability {
    void doAbility();
}

class Firebending implements Ability {
    private Mob mob;

    public Firebending(Mob mob) {
        this.mob = mob;
    }

    void doAbility() {
        // mutate mob's state to spit fire, and attack the world
    }
} // repeat this for each ability you have, flying, x-ray vision, doing taxes etc

class Mob {
    private Ability[] abilities;

    public Mob(Ability[] abilities) {
        this.abilities = abilities;
    }
}
```

With *something like this*, you can build different mobs on the fly each with a different set of abilities, suitable for when the mob varieties outnumber the number of abilities. And yes, this would involve designing your Mob class(es) to be flexible to be mutated this way.

Comment: That is perfect for what I want to do. Thank you!

Comment: Well, there is a circular dependency... But that could be worked out without too much trouble I think. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Cool question and one I fought back and forth with. It turns out that you probably will end up in a code trap , mostly due to a strictly object oriented design approach. Having written a number of game engines I might propose an alternative thought process.

Image if you had a skeleton that needs a shield and a sword, but can at any time not have a shield, maybe you drop it, or conversely drop the sword (or both). To code this using Object Oriented design only, we would attempt to subclass from the skeleton and extend the class to have the skeleton with sword instance, but what about with shield, or with sword and shield, or both, or neither. To accomplish you could bang on it and force OOP design but as with all things, eventually the game designer will ask you to change the skeleton in some way that will cause a significant code change and you can forget about loosely coupled object sharing (say the skeleton drops the sword and the knight picks it up).

Having dealt with this and understating where you are right now, I'd suggest researching an [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system).

Here the Game assets are split into Entities, Components, and Systems.

Entities: Is a simple list of integers where each integer is a component id. This allows components such as the SwordComponent to be shared across any other component. Think of an entity as a collection of components that a system can use to do some game action.

Components: A component is a simple class that ONLY contains data fields, never implementation. Each component gets a unique ID and the specific fields needed to define the component. Here I find it okay to use OOP to subclass the Component class so I really use a mix of both worlds.

System: Systems are where things get interesting. While entities are just list that combine components, and components are just data and state info, systems act on the component data to make entities work. Here you may pass in an entity and have some game logic act on the data. Systems are where you would put the code that makes each entity tick.

Here is an outline of our skeleton example:

```
Component[0]: Skeleton Mesh 
Component[1]: Idle Animation  
Component[2]: Walk Animation 
Component[3]: Run Animation 
Component[4]: Collision 
Component[5]: Sound 
Component[6]: Sword 
Component[7]: Shield 
Component[8]: Clown Suit
```

Skeleton Entity:

```
Entity[0] = new int {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} // Defines all the components above into one character
```

Possible Systems:

```
System[0] = Collision system handles polygon collisions, using all entities collision components.
System[1] = Animation system uses idle, walk, and run animation components and can be shared across entities.
System[2] = Render system is used to render the mesh using your render engine. 
System[3] = Sound system is used to handle sound start, end, tween...
System[4] = ...
```

Now if the designer wants the skeleton to be able to sprout wings and fly, I don't worry about changing any previous code, I just create a new WingsComponent, add it to my entities component list, and code the new system to make the skeleton fly. Now I can freely extend my component and system pool without worrying about breaking changes.

Comment: I may have actually used the concept of a component in my game. For example, I have a class called "Assets", which contains a static list of every image in the game. In order for an object to get an image, it would need an ID which is set when an image is added to the image bank. Would that be an example of a component? Also, is what your saying here to have each entity completely comprised of a list of components which controls it's every action? What if needs to store aditional information somewhere? (position, attacking stage, etc.)

Comment: Have a read here, http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html
the Bjorn class is his entity.